# Include specific assembly types in other assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

So I have this huge solution containing more than 50 projects with thousands of source files. One of the projects which's namespace looks like this `nslevel1.nslevel2.nslevel3`, contains an interface `interface1`. then in the other project I am referencing that first project and implementing the `interface1`, suppose that class is called `class1`.

The  output type of those two projects are class libraries.

Now I want to give my coworker the `*.dll` file of the second project so he can reuse my code. For that I also have to give him the first project `*.dll` file because the `interface1`, which is implemented by `class1`, is defined in first project.

Now my question is: Can I somehow manage to give my coworker just a single `.dll` file. I really need to keep the `interfac1` and `class1` in different assemblies, if not that, putting `interface1` in same assembly as `class1` would have solved the problem.

Comment: So you want to give your coworker a single DLL, but you *also* want the types to be in different assemblies? That just doesn't make sense as a requirement. You could start with two assemblies and merge them into a single assembly (search for ilmerge)... is that what you meant?

Comment: I just wanted to know if there was any theoretical way to do that. apparently there is. okay thanks. but I don't understand what is the point of down-voting. if I knew the answer or any solution to the question why I would have asked it here. any way thanks for commenting

Comment: @Dima: just to be clear, the downvote is not mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) the resulting source files. this will allow you to mash the IL into a single file.

Since they need to be distributed as a single dll, and depending on the complexity of each projects' file structure, you could also create a new project and use the "Add Existing" dialog to "add as link" all the files from both projects, resulting in a single dll which is both projects merged as one.